# Create multiple column stacked graphs with two series

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create 40 different column stacked graphs using macros in Excel. Each graph has two series. So far I've done this:

```
Sub loopChart()

    Dim mychart As Chart
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim d As Integer
    c = 1
    d = 2

    While c <= 33 '1=dataSource1, 4=dataSource2, 7=dataSource3
    While d <= 33
        'set data source for the next chart
        With Worksheets("Hoja1")
            Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1, c), .Cells(3, c + 1))
            Set myRange2 = .Range(.Cells(1, d), .Cells(3, d + 1))
        End With

        'create chart
        Sheets("Hoja1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

        With ActiveChart
            .ChartType = xl3DColumnStacked
            'sets source data for graph including labels
            .SetSourceData Source:=myRange2, PlotBy:=xlColumns
            'including legend
            .SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
            .HasTitle = True
            'dimentions & location:
            'defines the coordinates of the top of the chart
            .Parent.Top = 244
            'defines the coordinates for the left side of the chart
            .Parent.Left = c * 100
            .Parent.Height = 200
            .Parent.Width = 300
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Porcenta-2014"
        End With

        c = c + 3
        d = d + 3
    Wend
    Wend

End Sub
```

I want that insted of *1* and *2* my graphs use de name of the column A:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you extend your range? So instead of initializing `d=2`, try `d=1` and add a header for it too.

Comment: please don't use 3D effect charts. They are so hard to read. It's impossible to tell how high the column is because you can't align the top edge of the column to the grid. It would be easy with a 2D chart. Don't do things with charts because the "look nice". Do things that make a chart easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub tset()

Dim dataRange As Range
Dim dataNames As Range
Dim c As Integer

Set dataRange = Range("B1:C3")
Set dataNames = Range("A2:A3")
c = 1

For i = 1 To 40
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
With ActiveChart
        .SetSourceData Source:=dataRange, PlotBy:=xlColumns
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = dataNames
        .ChartType = xl3DColumnStacked
        .SetElement (msoElementLegendRight)
        .HasTitle = True
        .Parent.Top = 244
        .Parent.Left = c * 100
        .Parent.Height = 200
        .Parent.Width = 300
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Porcenta-2014"
End With
c = c + 3
Set dataRange = dataRange.Offset(0, 2)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Péter Oravecz. Thank you so much my friend.